# Using Git on Mac? I cant find git-svn

Tags: macos, git, git-svn

I am trying to use git on the Mac OS X and I can't find `git-svn` to do something like

```
git-svn clone -s http://example.com/my_subversion_repo local_dir
```

is

```
git svn clone -s http://example.com/my_subversion_repo local_dir
```

The same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though I've never used the feature, I believe those two should be equivalent. My reasoning is:

- performing simply `git svn` results in the error that .git wasn't found, within the script `/usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn`;
- opening that script in a text editor reveals the credit of the author of git-svn:

> Copyright (C) 2006, Eric Wong

- hence running `git svn help` gives:

> git-svn - bidirectional operations between a single Subversion tree and git

Comment: The command `git FOO` means to run the command `git-FOO` found in /usr/libexec/git-core (which path is the default value of the `--exec-path` option.)

Comment: @chepner that would appear to be an authoritative answer and is much more that a mere comment on mine; if you want to promote it to an answer you'll certainly get a +1 from me.

Comment: so is "git svn" on mac the same as "git-svn" on linux

Comment: @techsjs2013 yes. It is.